Is there a way to avoid android(13) pairing window and do it by device address automatically?
The following program section (java) is working fine, the file can be received, I just want to get rid of choosing device manually.
I wonder if there is a simple way using intent.putExtra with device address, without using socket.
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("*/*");
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");
    File privateFile = new File(privateFileName);
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, this.getPackageName() + ".provider", privateFile);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    this.grantUriPermission("com.android.bluetooth", uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION |       Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(sendIntent);

I have tried something like this, but nothing happened:
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(device_address);
    sendIntent.putExtra( "android.bluetooth.device.extra.DEVICE", device);

I am not sure if this is even resolvable, so any help or opinion would be highly appreciated, thank you.
